# Get Pipeline Value of GitHub Issues?

Tags: github, github-api, zenhub

I use ZenHub to manage my Issues on GitHub. 
When I go to the detail of an issue I can see the property "pipeline" in GitHub which is exactly the column where the Issue is saved.

Now I want to get the pipeline information out of my issues using the API of GitHub. But none of the Issue-Methods 
`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues` or `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number` seem to have any information about the pipeline. Is it hidden anywhere else?[image]

Comment: I'd be surprised if you *could* see it over the GitHub API. ZenHub is a browser extension, which (probably) doesn't store its data in GitHub's back-end.

Comment: I thought, this property is always there, and ZenHub just displays it in a fancy way?!?

Comment: Nope, GitHub issues don't have anything called a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Github API v4, you can query the [combinedContexts of a commit](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/objects#status) to retrieve a list of [status contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/objects#statuscontext) and check runs for the commit triggering your pipelines.

Comment: @VonC thanks, and congrats for your million ^^

Comment: Thank you. I still need a day or two, but I will get there ;)

Answer (score 9):

**[Pipeline](https://github.com/ZenHubIO/support/search?q=pipeline&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)** is purely a [ZenHub](https://www.zenhub.io/features) feature.

As such, it is not exposed in the [Github API Issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) (or in any other GitHub API)

A ZenHub public API is in the making ([issue 172](https://github.com/ZenHubIO/support/issues/172)).

**Update:** The API is available: [ZenHub API](https://github.com/ZenHubIO/API)